# sql - Finding cost between two graph points

Tags: mysql, sql, graph

I have a table that stores the time between two adjacent railway stations.

```
+------+------+------+
| s1id | s2id | tbtw |
+------+------+------+
| 234  | 235  | 20   |
| 235  | 133  | 8    |
| 133  | 108  | 15   |
| 234  | 236  | 10   |
| 108  | 500  | 2    |
| 235  | 108  | 21   |
+------+------+------+
```

I want to find the time between any two point, if they can be connected like finding the time from station 234 to 500 (234->235->108->500). I know this is like a graph. I have tried to find the cumulative distance with t2.s1id = t1.s2id as follows

```
select t1.* SUM(t2.tbtw) as sum
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.s2id = t2.s1id
group by t1.id, t1.tbtw
```

but this is not giving me cumulative time or doesn't properly link with the nodes

```
select t1.*
   (select sum(tbtw)
    from t t2
    where t2.s1id = t1.s2.id
   ) as sum
from t t1;
```

I can easily do it in a programming language, but in sql, its really confusing. Do I have to use procedures? Can't I do in simple sql statements? The solution is preferred in simple sql statements, however other solutions are also okay. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see article: http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html

i guess it is helpfull

Comment: Thanks, exactly the one I want

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of the examples on that site implement CTEs, which MySQL doesn't support. You will have to refactor some of those designs to use inline views or something similar.